# How can I convert image sequence to quicktime movie?

Tags: java, image, video, quicktime, mov

I have been searching on this. I Need to build an independent utility that should:

- Convert image sequence to .mov format
- Take input from user and display it inside the mov.

I plan to do this using Java since this is a cross platform language.

How to do it?

Comment: *"take input from user"*  Besides the image names of files, what 'input'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`JpegImagesToMovie.java`](http://www.koders.com/java/fid8AE9208DC5FB846910DFD3F935D64E7C9A5BB784.aspx) it requires the x-plat version of the JMF (or more importantly `jmf.jar`).

For a more modern alternative, look to [JFFMPEG](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/)  (JMF with more formats & encodings).

Answer (score 1):

I have earlier used [XUGGLER](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) for making videos from image frames. It is easy to use XUGGLER with the help of the comprehensive tutorials available [here](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Tutorials). You can also add audio to the video generated from the image frames.

Xuggler supports a large number of video codecs and video container formats so you will have the option of creating the video in different formats, leave alone .mov. Hope this helps. I can post my own code for this utility if required.